# ag-grid-angular toolPanelVisibleChanged does not work

Tags: ag-grid

[Reproducible example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nh7EzRdDD11oiIRcVZbD?p=preview)

Setting the `toolPanelVisibleChanged` event on `ag-grid-angular` does not appear to capture the event.

I've logged out the event object to the console, but nothing appears when the panel is shown/hidden.

The template has:

```
(toolPanelVisibleChanged)="onToolPanelVisible($event)"
```

And the template class has:

```
onToolPanelVisible(event) { console.log(event); }
```

However nothing is logged out to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are on a AG-Grid version which is at least 20.1.0. Your problem was a bug and should be solved with version 20.1.0.

The bug was reported via https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2763

Ticket for the bug was: AG-2234 (https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/)

Comment: @dippas I think I explained that this behavior, which is the problem, was a bug in the library and was solved because it was reported via Github. I just linked to the issue for clarity and to the changelog for traceability.